# Unable to find an entry point named '<function>' in DLL '<DLL_name>'

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I want to call method "Talk" from C#. I went through the other related posts, but it did not help me.

> Managed.Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Managed
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("Unmanaged.exe", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl,EntryPoint="Talk",CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int Talk();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int value=Talk();
        }
    }
}
```

> Unmanaged.h

```
#ifndef UNMANAGED_H
#define UNMANAGED_H
extern "C"
{
__declspec(dllexport) int Talk();
}
#endif
```

> Unmanaged.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "Unmanaged.h"

int Talk()
{
    int x=10,y=5;
    return (x+y);
}
```

Comment: Have you copied your unmanaged DLL into the same folder as the C# executable? [EDIT] Wait, you're calling into an EXE? You shouldn't do that. You need to create a DLL.

Comment: Go to your client application -->Add-->Existing item--> got to your the path where your dll is generated-->select the DLL --> Add as a link and you are done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to deploy your library as `DLL`. `DllImport` will only work for .dll-libraries using P/Ivoke.

When creating a DLL in VS, choose a **Console Application** under Win32 and set the radio-button to "Dynamic-Link-Library (DLL)".

Then do as you did. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for some information.